# Conditional Formatting rules for the whole worksheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

In Excel itself, Conditional Formatting menu, one can select the rules within the whole worksheet. Yet, in VBA, FormatConditions is a property of a range, and not a property of the sheet object. How can get that list of FormatConditions which is displayed in the Excel as applying to the whole sheet?

Answer (score 0):

The `.cells` property of a worksheet is a range that contains all cells of the sheet.

You can use a code like that to create a rule for the whole sheet:

```
With ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=VALUE(A1)>50")
    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
End With
```